# How to wait until a bunch of calls ends to make another call

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I'm using `RxJava` and I know about `concat`, and I guess it does fit to me, because I want to finish first all of first call and then do the second one but I don't know how to implement it.

I have this from now :

```
private fun assignAllAnswersToQuestion(questionId: Long) {

        answerListCreated.forEach { assignAnswerToQuestion(questionId, it.id) }

    }

    private fun assignAnswerToQuestion(questionId: Long, answerId: Long) {
        disposable = questionService.addAnswerToQuestion(questionId,answerId,MyUtils.getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage(context = this))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                {
                    result -> //Do nothing it should call the next one

                },
                { error -> toast(error.message.toString())}
            )
    }
```

But then, once this is finished all of this `forEach` I'd like to do something like this :

```
private fun assignAllAnswersToQuestion(questionId: Long) {

   answerListCreated.forEach { assignAnswerToQuestion(questionId, it.id) 
   anotherCallHere(questionId) //Do it when the first forEach is finished!!

}
```

Any idea?

Also, is a way to do it with coroutines this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to `.map` your list (`answerListCreated`) to a list of `Flowable`s, and then use `Flowable.zip` on this list.
`zip` is used to combine the results of the `Flowable`s into a single result. Since you don't need these results we ignore them.
After `zip` you are sure that all previous `Flowable`s ended, and you can `.flatMap` to execute your next call (assuming `anotherCallHere` returns a `Flowable`.

In the end, it will be something like:

```
val flowableList = answerListCreated.map { assignAnswerToQuestion(questionId, it.id) }

disposable = Flowable.zip(flowableList) { /* Ignoring results */ }
    .flatMap { anotherCallHere(questionId) }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe {
        // ...
    }
```

It should be noted that if any of the calls fails, the whole chain will fail (`onError` will be called).

Comment: And then how do I call my second method?

Comment: I mean, first I want to add on my list 1,2,3,4,5 and then grab the 3 for example, so I want to finish first the add to list and then make the call grabX

Comment: When you use `zip` you pass a list of `Flowable`s and lambda. Inside the lambda you can access the results of the `Flowable`s you passed in. Like this:
`Flowable.zip(flowableList) { resultList -> /* Use list of results */ }`

Comment: So if you take a look to my question, I've edited a little bit  reading from "But then" how can I achieve this code?  can you edit your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what you are asking. My current answer solves this problem: 1) execute **all** `assignAnswerToQuestion` calls 2) then executes `anotherCallHere`.

Comment: And what's iniside subscribe? The result of anotherCallHere?

Comment: Yes, since inside `subscribe` you have the latest result of the chain.

Comment: So in subscribe it only returns the result of the last call?

Comment: Yes. If you want to keep the other results you have to combine them into a single one and pass it downstream.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190243/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-gpunto).

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to coroutines but I think I can answer for them:

You can use coroutines runBlocking {} for this.

```
private fun assignAllAnswersToQuestion(questionId: Long) = launch {
    runBlocking {
        answerListCreated.forEach { assignAnswerToQuestion(questionId, it.id) }
    }
    anotherCallHere(questionId)
}

private fun assignAnswerToQuestion(questionId: Long, answerId: Long) = launch (Dispatchers.IO) {
    questionService.addAnswerToQuestion(
        questionId,
        answerId,
        MyUtils.getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage(context = this)
    )
}
```

launch {} returns a Job object which becomes a child job of the parent coroutine. runBlocking {} will block until all its child jobs have finished, (an alternative is to use launch {}.join() which will have the same affect).

Note that I have made both functions wrap their code in a launch {} block.
To be able to call launch {} like this, you will likely want to make your class implement [CoroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html)

```
class MyActivityOrFragment: Activity(), CoroutineScope {
    lateinit var job = SupervisorJob()
    private val exceptionHandler =
        CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, error ->
            toast(error.message.toString()
        }
    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job + exceptionHandler

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        job = Job()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel()
    }

    ...
}
```